# How to send hidden request to page?

Tags: vbscript, request

Is there possibility to make computer enter website `www.example.com/something.php?something=something`, without that user sees it?

I am in mind to make user start program, VBS script goes to website listed above, and will deliever information, and later, I will make it work myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an HTTP POST request. In VBScript you'd do it like this:

```
url = "http://www.example.com/something.php&something=something"
url = Split(url, "&", 2)

Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
req.open "POST", url(0), False
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.send url(1)
```

You may need to encode the parameter string (`url(1)`) passed to the `send` method with something like this:

```
Function Encode(ByVal str)
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.~-]"

  enc = ""
  For i = 1 To Len(str)
    c = Mid(str, i, 1)
    If re.Test(c) Then c = "%" & Right("0" & Hex(Asc(c)), 2)
    enc = enc & c
  Next

  Encode = enc
End Function
```

Comment: Yeah... but is there possibility to send request to specific page? Because you did "`something=something`", but it was just example. Is it possible to visit just one specific link? My link could be `www.example.com/something.php` or even `www.example.com` I need just enter that one specific **full** link.

Comment: It should be possible, although it's hard to say with such vague specifications. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to use POST instead of GET.  Not sure how VBS is being used but if you do a form post into something.php you can use the super global $_POST variable to extract your form variables without the user seeing the variables in the address.

Comment: Gah, I didn't ment to work with PHP. I want to user send data to server, and on server, I will make PHP and MySQL functions. I know how, I need just get data to the server by `$_GET[];` function. Without that disturbs user.

Comment: Your comment hasn't clarified the issue. Perhaps you should consider rephrasing your question and explain how you see the different elements working together.